# Почему ставится запятая перед союзом ИЛИ?

Tags: пунктуация, грамматика, или

Как  можно объяснить постановку запятой перед союзом ИЛИ (по правилам Розенталя  или ПАС), а также какова грамматика следующего предложения:

*А суматоха была оттого, что Анна Павловна отпускала сына в Петербург на службу, **или, как она говорила, людей посмотреть и себя показать***.

Обыкновенная история (И.А. Гончаров).

Мне встречались объяснения в Сети, но они не показались мне  корректными. Хотелось бы узнать ваше мнение, тем более что здесь не исключены разные варианты ответов.

Также надо иметь в виду, что это **учебный пример**, то есть ответ должны дать школьники, исходя из своего уровня знаний.

Для них задание оказалось трудным, и некоторые считали такое предложение сложным. Вероятно, они полагали, что вводное предложение входит в основное сообщение и к нему относили заключительную часть.

Спасибо.

Comment: А здесь реально много вариантов восприятия: *Отпускала сына в Петербург на службу, а на самом деле людей посмотреть и себя показать* (так понял изначально). *Отпускала сына в Петербург на службу, а больше чтобы людей посмотреть и себя показать. Отпускала сына в Петербург на службу, или людей посмотреть и себя показать на службе* (нестандартный пояснительный член с ИЛИ; прочтение так неудачно из-за семантического различия). *Отпускала сына в Петербург на службу, или людей посмотреть и себя показать в Петербурге* (присоединение).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вообще "людей посмотреть и себя показать" может пояснять "на службу"? Разве в этом служба заключается? Это **совсем разные вещи**. Там не пояснительная конструкция с ИЛИ, так как она предполагает **второе название** (или же то, как можно **это же** сказать иначе). В этом случае варианты тождественны, между ними можно вставить слово "это". А здесь ИЛИ указывает на второй вариант (разделительное значение), а не поясняет первый.

Это можно объяснить только **присоединением** — в значении "ну или". Зачем оно нужно? Такое применяется, когда первый вариант **неправдоподобный** (в него мало кто поверит), а потом даётся более честный вариант.

Пример:
*Он поехал получать высшее образование, ну или на Москву посмотреть.*
Примеры из Нацкорпуса:
*Большинство из вас уже играли, ну или хотя бы слышали об игре в замкнутом пространстве.

Пока я не чувствую здесь себя за границей… Ну, или почти не чувствую.

Книжку нужно покупать в теплом, специально оборудованном для этого помещении, чтобы вокруг была умная, спокойная тишина, а книжек было от горизонта до горизонта, ну или хотя бы от стены до угла.

Нет-нет, этой сцены просто не было. Ну, или она ничего не означает.

А в Америку ехали все, у кого было слишком много энергии для тусклого проживания на исторической родине. Ну или кого допекли.*

**Примеры Розенталя из темы "Присоединительные конструкции":**
*Опытный спринтер оказался на десять метров, или около этого, впереди других.

И детей оставили, или почти что оставили, в покое.

Внезапно мальчик исчез — умер, или, возможно, его похитили.*
http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=120

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129070/discussion-on-answer-by-oleedd------).

Answer (score 3):

Запятая ставится потому, что тут пояснительная конструкция, которая поясняет сочетание «на службу».
Вот несколько примеров из Розенталя:
По всей ширине Лены торчали в разных направлениях огромные льдины, или, по-местному, торосья (Кор.);
Электронные лампы, или, как их правильнее называют, электровакуумные приборы, изготовляются разного назначения;
…Это был Александр Тимофеевич, или попросту Саша, гость, приехавший из Москвы (Ч.);
На берегу было много гальки, или мелких, гладко обточенных водой камней.

Можно счесть сочетание после «или» частью сложносочиненного, но это никак не повлияет на пунктуацию, а сделает эту часть пояснительно-сложносочиненной.
Примеры очень подходят: имеют одну и ту же схему — пояснительный союз «или» + вводное слово источника сообщения + другой способ обозначить что-то словами. Вне зависимости от того, сложное ли это предложение или нет, но это пояснительное сочетание и пунктуация здесь одинакова.

Возможно, некоторые люди не видят здесь пояснение потому, что не знают, что «отправится на службу» в 19 веке для представителя высших слоев отчасти и означало «людей посмотреть и себя показать». Взгляните на отрывок из Капитанской дочки Пушкина:
Мысль о службе сливалась во мне с мыслями о свободе, об удовольствиях петербургской жизни. Я воображал себя офицером гвардии, что, по мнению моему, было верхом благополучия человеческого.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129082/discussion-on-answer-by-jim-korbett------).

Answer (score 2):

Комментарии

1. Интересный диалог, и каждый отвечающий по-своему прав. Дело в том, что  слово пояснение  (внесение ясности) – многозначное, и даже  в правописании  мы используем два значение – общее и частное. Говорить об общем пояснении можно во многих случаях, считая любую  дополнительную информацию пояснением. Но есть еще и конкретное значение – **пояснительный член предложения**, а это уже более четкое определение. И вот в этом смысле информация в конце фразы после союза ИЛИ **к пояснению не относится.**
2. @oleedd.  вы, как мне кажется,  на правильном пути, но объяснение  **присоединительного значения** не кажется убедительным. У вас очень частное толкование, а в данном случае нужны обобщенные показания для того, чтобы считать конструкцию присоединительной.

Может ли **союз ИЛИ** быть присоединительным? Обычно мы указываем два его значения – разделительное или пояснительное, причем разница между ними не всегда очевидна. Есть ли основания считать, что союз ИЛИ имеет **три значения**?

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ** ОТ 30.08.2021

Мой заключительный **ВЫВОД** по теме такой.

**Семантических оттенков** может быть много,  но **грамматических форм** для их выражения ограниченное количество, и их нужно хорошо знать. Мне важно было (по официальным правилам!) обозначить **статус союза ИЛИ в трех вариантах** – разделительный, пояснительный и присоединительный.

Два первых варианта используются  в конкретных темах, указанных в словаре (их не так много). Гораздо свободнее по тематике **присоединительные конструкции** – это разный синтаксис (слова, словосочетания, предложения и т.д.). Именно под эту категории удобно подвести заданное предложение.

Присоединительные конструкции содержат **дополнительную информацию** различного характера, в том числе **пояснительную** (в общем понимании этого слова).

**ОТВЕТ:**  Это простое предложение, осложненное вводным предложением и обособленным присоединительным оборотом пояснительного характера (присоединительный союз ИЛИ).

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129072/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon------).

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю ничего. Я бы ответил, что запятая ставится исходя из двух основ, которые связывает союз *или*.

Comment: Там вводное предложение, а оно не относится к основному сообщению и в состав предложения не входит.

Comment: @Sharon  Понятно, что вводное предложение ни при чем, но там действительно две основы: *Анна Павловна отпускала* и *посмотреть и показать*.

Comment: @Александр Стрелец  Ваши инфинитивы в качестве основы   для придаточного подходят, а если союза ЧТОБЫ нет, то это обстоятельства цели. Или нет?

Comment: Хорошо, пусть они будут не основа. Я всё равно понимаю так: *служба = себя показать и людей посмотреть*.  P. S. И опять - почему только я поставил плюс вам за вопрос? Отвечающие, а-уу!

Comment: Если вы с Анной Павловной согласны, то да. Но в любом случае у нас присоединительная конструкция (обособленные обстоятельства),осложненная вводным предложением; присоединительный союз ИЛИ. С таким решением вы согласны?  Вы говорили, что это пояснение. Другое мнение - это присоединение  с добавочным значением пояснения.

Comment: Ну вот, присоединение с пояснением. Два в одном. Очень хорошо. По большому счету, какая разница? Ведь без запятой здесь не обойтись, да и пауза очень кстати.

Comment: Вообще не вижу пояснения, оно было бы, если было бы сказано, где, как и кем надо будет служить в Петербурге. А "людей посмотреть и себя показать" — это следствия поездки и более честная причина "отпускания" сына в Петербург.

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец Разница в том, что совсем по-другому читается. При пояснительном ИЛИ — как однородные элементы, но с паузой.